# ArcMap Field Calculator Remove Null values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser, null

I would like to remove the NULL/empty values from a table that is stored in a Geodatabase. Last time I tried doing so it worked fine, today I have some issues with the codes (Double Field). I have used the following python sequence;

Pre-logic:

```
def RemoveNULL(x):
  if x is None:
    return '0'
  elif x == ' ':
    return '0'
  else: return x
```

Second Field:

```
    RemoveNULL(!Field_name!)
```

According to my opinion the code is correct but the Geoprocessing window illustrates a failure each time I calculate just after 1-3 seconds.

Comment: What is the error message that you get?

Comment: Hello Martin, the error message is a generic one: 'ERROR 999999: Error executing function'. Below, I have two more; 'Expected 'Then'' and ' Failed to execute (CalculateField)'. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Im sure this is Python and not VB script. By putting the 0 in speech marks, you are trying to say that 0 is a string, when its not. As added by Martin, please select the Python Parser instead of the VB Script Parser.
Try and use the following code:

```
def RemoveNULL(x):
  if x is None:
    return 0
  elif x == ' ':
    return 0
  else: 
    return x
```

Comment: Yeah, and also make sure to use the Python parser!

Comment: Using the Python parser and the amended code helped. Thank you both very much!